# UIWebView white flashing when load page

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview

i have build a WebApp for iOS. When i click/tap to move to a page for example from page - index.html to page2.html it flashing white. Did you know why, and how to solve this problem?

The Websites works fantastic in Browser (Safari, IE, Firefox and Chrome) but not as an Application.

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")!)))


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Why are You setting `alpha` to 0?

Comment: Just to test it. I thought maybe it solved the problem.

Comment: So, even without `alpha` Your `webView` is flashing? And what means flashing?

Comment: With flashing i mean a "flickering" / "flashing" page by load. When i click on a button to move from pageA.html to pageB.html its first "flash" / "flicker" before completely show the page. it don't show the pageB.html instantly .. in the inspector i have set the background of UIWebView to white, so its flicker white.. when i set it to red, its flicker in red.. but if i set it to clear with zero opacity it also flicker/flash in grey..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code will help you!

Step 1: Fetch `UIWebView` and `UIActivityIndicatorView` to your view controller.
Step 2: Delegate `UIWebView` to viewController and Create outlets for `UIWebView` and `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Step 3: Select `UIActivityIndicatorView` on view controller then go to **Attributes Inspector ->Activity Indicator View -> check Animating and Hides when Stopped on Behaviour**

Step 4: Add Below codes to your `ViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false //to avoid auto scrolling.
        functionOfWebView()

    }

    func functionOfWebView()
    {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        //let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")  //For local html file(index.html) with local file hyperlink(file.html) see on video tutorial
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        loader.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        loader.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false //to avoid auto scrolling.
        functionOfWebView()
    }

    func functionOfWebView()
    {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        //let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")  //For local html file(index.html) with local file hyperlink(file.html) see on video tutorial
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        loader.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        loader.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]

if you confuse or for Using Local html files then see this [Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/6iHt6UEZQ88)

Comment: thanks for the code. It works, but for my website it take a long time to load. My website is a one page website with many section/panel which is very big. the heigh is 38400px (768px * 50). and the links are anchor links.
**
2016-08-04 11:36:38.952 webApp[3058:3565120] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2016-08-04 11:36:41.970 webApp[3058:3565039] Received memory warning.
2016-08-04 11:36:42.166 webApp[3058:3565039] Received memory warning.**

Comment: Kindly, Check Youtube Tutorial :) I shown your required thing on that video.[I make this video for you!](https://youtu.be/6iHt6UEZQ88)

Comment: thank you very much for all your efforts! I have watched the video and added the code in my Xcode Project but the flicker/flashing issue is still exist :(

Comment: Ouch! I don't get that Kind of effect! so the coding is correct. Please check your system and check it output on iOS Device :) :)

Comment: flicker or flashing comes everytime when i click on a button or an anchor link.. :/ evertime when the page need to be reloaded. : /

Comment: Are you check your output on iOS Device?

Comment: what does you mean with " output on iOS Device? "

Comment: oops sorry! Connect your iPhone to your laptop and check it is your web view work on iPhone... can you get it?

Comment: all interaction from html works on iPad, also animation, video etc. still working, but the flashing and flickering issue is not solved :( it comes when i click on any button by loading another page.. :(